# getting data form NSMutable dictionar in ISO 6

Tags: ios

my code have data in NSMutableDictionary named

```
resultDic=
(
    {
    Address = "Rwp,Pak";
    Age = 29;
    CliniID = 1;
    Description = "Fever from 3 days";
    DiaStolicBP = 80;
    DoctorID = 2006;
    Gender = male;
    Name = Tim;
    PatientID = 1002;
    Pluse = 92;
    Symptoms = "Feeling Cold";
    SystolicBP = 120;
    Temperature = 104;
    Weigth = 59;
    }
)
```

I extract object of Dictionary by using this code:

```
NSString *age =[resultDic valueForKey:@"Age"];
it returns result:
(
    29
)
```

Now the problem is I want the result just:
29
help me in this code Will be v.greatfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now it's clear.

add following lines in that case when you don't know exact place of '(' and ')' symbols,

```
// you have result = @"(37)";
NSString *age = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
NSString *age = [age stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
// getting age = @"37"
```

otherwise if you know that you have string starting with '(' and one ')' at the end, you might do this way

```
NSRange range;
range.location = 1;
range.length = [result length]-1;
NSString *age = [result substringWithRange:range];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: just to have NSString Age=29 istead Age=(29)